# HTTP 400 has an empty response only in production

Tags: javascript, http, api-platform.com

There's a strange behavior happening with my api-plateform API.

**In local developement**, when I send a POST or PUT on a route with a body that violates one of the constraints I have implemented, the API sends back an error 400 with the correct response :

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
    "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "center: Cette valeur ne doit pas être nulle.\nacronym: Cette chaîne est trop longue. Elle doit avoir au maximum 10 caractères.",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "center",
            "message": "Cette valeur ne doit pas être nulle."
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "acronym",
            "message": "Cette chaîne est trop longue. Elle doit avoir au maximum 10 caractères."
        }
    ]
}
```

**When I try the same request in a remote production environnent**, the same request gives me an error 400, **but with no response attached to it.**

What is strange is that when I try the same request within the Swagger UI or Postman, I get the expected correct response.

So it only happens on the frontend app making the request.

**I also have no issue with any other request. A correct POST will come through, a GET will give me a correct response, etc. The only problem is the 400 error with no response attached.**

I suspect the culprit to be linked to the CORS configuration of my API, but it seems fine to me :

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: []
    allow_headers: []
    allow_methods: []
    expose_headers: ['Content-Disposition', 'Content-Length', 'Link']
    max_age: 0
    hosts: []
    origin_regex: false
    forced_allow_origin_value: ~
paths:
    '^/api':
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
    '^/': ~
```

Here is an example of my front-end request headers :

```
:authority: *myProductionApiUrl*
:method: POST
:path: /api/trainings
:scheme: https
accept: application/ld+json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
authorization: *Bearer mytoken*
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 151
content-type: application/ld+json
origin: http://localhost:3000
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:3000/app/trainings/create
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
```

**UPDATE :** This is definitely a CORS issue, and *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*.

The question remains : how can I get this CORS header issue on POST and PUT request, but not on GET, OPTIONS, etc.

Furthermore, I have no problem when doing a POST that results in a successful creation (201).